# How do I manage regular fscks for large amounts of data?

Tags: fsck

I'm guessing there's a recommended size that doing fsck would be counter productive, say if the size is 100TB or greater doing it with the default setting of 30 or 20 mounts or 180 days is a bit excessive, production environment can't be down that long provided that the backup of said data are there.

So is there a limit or paper on "yeah, after that (n)size it's suggested that the default settings change to something else (80-100 mounts) 300 days etc".

Answer (score 0):

A 100TB filesystem sounds like a fairly bad idea (as you've clearly realised). I suggest dividing it into smaller filesystems if you can, for sanity. I quite like Val Henson's (now slightly dated) talk [Choosing and Tuning Linux File Systems](http://valerieaurora.org/review/choosing.pdf), for an overview on how to take the right paths and get the most out of filesystems.

Anyway, to actually answer your question. See the [tune2fs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/tune2fs) `-c` and `-i` options. e.g.

```
sudo tune2fs -i 300d -c 100 /dev/bigfs
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I'm actually looking for a standard/optimized setting that a white paper or industry best practices came up with.  And of course breaking it into smaller chunks are not always possible so if it's standard to turn it off all together then it's ok too.

Comment: I think that'll depend a lot on the environment. But yes, turning it off isn't totally insane. You just need to be aware that you could end up with long-term, undetected corruption.

Comment: ah ok thanks for your time.  I was hoping to have a standard justified settings that was recommended, I guess I just have to make something up and call it  day.